# How to get Observable that emits only when a property value changes in an array of objects in redux state?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngredux

I have redux state in angular app:

```
export interface UIAction {
  name: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
    
export interface IUIState {
  actions: UIAction[];
}
```

I have built an angular service that subscribes to the state and stores Subjects for each action in a Map and returns that subject for callers that are interested in isActive-value for a certain action. It's something like this:

```
public getIsActive$(name: string): Observable<boolean> {  
  let sub = this.subsMap.get(name);
  return sub.asObservable();
}
```

Now I want to change the code and get rid of the Map with all the Subjects and do something like this:

```
public getIsActive$(name: string): Observable<boolean> {  
  return this.ngRedux.select<IUIState>('ui').pipe(
  /* this should use some operators so that
     the returned Observable emits only when 
     UIAction.isActive changes for the action 
     in question. The action in question is
     found from the state.actions-array using 
     parameter 'name' */
   )));
}
```

How this should be done? Below an example.

Initially the UIState.actions looks like this:

```
[ { name: 'Save', isActive: false }, { name: 'Cancel', isActive: true } ]
```

At this point I call

```
myService.getIsActive$('Save').subscribe(isActive => {
  console.log('Value : ${isActive});
});
```

then I dispatch a redux state change (only new values here):

```
{ name: 'Cancel', isActive: false }
```

The UIState.actions changes to:

```
[ { name: 'Save', isActive: false }, { name: 'Cancel', isActive: false} ]
```

The subscription however does not write to console because it wasn't subscribed to changes of 'Cancel' action.

Then I dispatch another redux state change (only values here):

```
{ name: 'Save', isActive: true }
```

And the UIState.actions changes to:

```
[ { name: 'Save', isActive: true}, { name: 'Cancel', isActive: false} ]
```

Now the subscription writes to console:

```
Value: true
```

because it was subscribed to changes of 'Save' action.

Comment: Maybe [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) operator can help you

Comment: i just found it myself and think i got this

Comment: Since you're dealing with objects, `distinctUntilChanged()` won't work because every object reference is unique. Use `distinctUntilKeyChanged('isActive)` as it will run the condition for this specific object property.

Comment: I wrote `distinctUntilChanged` on purpose, cause you can specify a compare function, and I don’t think `distinctUntilKeyChanged` gonna help him because it’s an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in this, I did it like this. Thanks for others pointing me to right direction:

```
public getIsActive$(name: UIActionName): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.getUIAction$(name).pipe(
    map(axn => axn.isActive)).pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
}

private getUIAction$(name: UIActionName): Observable<UIAction> {
  return this.ngRedux.select<IUIState>('ui').pipe(map(state => {
    return state.actions.find(actn => actn.name === name);
  })).pipe(
    filter((axn: UIAction | undefined): axn is UIAction => axn !== undefined));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I'm understanding this requirement correctly. You can apply a custom function to `distinctUntilChanged()` for more complex cases.

```
public getIsActive$(name: string):Observable<boolean> {
  return this.ngRedux.select<IUIState>('ui').pipe(
    map(uiState=>uiState.find(state=>state.name===name)),
    filter(state=>!!state),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr)=>
      prev.name===curr.name && prev.isActive === curr.isActive
    ),
    map(state=>state.isActive)
  );
}
```

Here's a line-by-line of what's going on:

- Find the state inside the array based on its name
- Filter out in case `.find()` returns `undefined`
- Apply a custom function that checks both `name` and `isActive`. If either property doesn't match its previous value, it will emit the new value.
- Now that we have our new value, return the `isActive` boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the array that contain the items is called actions. so the item in question must be searched from uiState.actions. This is said in "commented code".

Comment: I updated my question to better explain what I need